# Trying to find a kids show about three kids with superpowers?

Tags: story-identification

Recently my mind was filled with these memories of a kids show about three kids with superpowers. It was an American show, I think, and animated.

The kids weren’t actually superpowered, though. I think they were just imagining it. One girl had super strength and flight, another girl had X-ray vision, and one boy had elasticity. Do any of you think you remember this show?

Comment: Disney's Zoom, perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi Stack Exchange! Do you have any more details to make answering this question easier? When was the show aired? What network was it on?

Comment: Hmm. Tempted to VTC as off-topic if they were just imagining their powers...

Comment: @Valorum "Just imagining" - I remember a show in which a gang of kids had special powers in the "dream world" - with which they fought evil spirits trying to cause nightmares - but not when they were awake. If the show OP has in mind turns out to be along the same lines, would you still consider it off-topic?